# Angular Js - Clicking on the same link doesn't reload the page

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Recently we started using Angular js and as result of using Angular js, we came across few issues.

1. Href doesn't reload the same page on clicking,  I have found one solution online but I am not sure if this is a good idea to use or not. Is there any way we can handle it from Angular js side?

([In an angular app, href in <a> doesn't reloads the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26437495/in-an-angular-app-href-in-a-doesnt-reloads-the-page))

2. Anchor links are not working. Previously only single # used to work and scroll was happening. Now it need the below format to scroll.

http://www.test.com/about**/#/#2308592**

I have a large website, I can't go and change all anchor to above format. Same way I can't put target="_self" to all my Href. Let me know if we have a solution from Angular Js side.

Comment: Have you tried angular service `anchorScroll`?

Comment: I have not used it because I want my previous implementation to work as it is. I don't want to change previous implementation to use anchorScroll. Why angular is effecting my previous implementation ?

Answer (score 0):

You could disable the default anchor behavior by using something from this answer -

[How to preventDefault on anchor tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10931315/how-to-preventdefault-on-anchor-tags)

And then control reload using -

```
$location.path(incomingPath);
$route.reload()
```

where you can get the 'incomingPath' for $location from the anchor's click event.

I do not think there's any other way apart from this without having to change the individual anchor tags to be Angular friendly.